# Azure pipeline missing references

Tags: asp.net-core, build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to use the Azure pipelines to build and publish my projects. Unfortunately there is not much documentation or Q&A around.

My solution contains 12 libraries, most with .net core/standard, one with angular (But this is not the problem). In visual studio building/publishing works. In my dev.azure workspace it doesn't.

this is my YAML-file

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

and the problem is, that all the references are missing while building:

> Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

[image]

does anyone have any idea on how to fix this? The nuget restore works.

Comment: And what does the output of the nuget restore activity say?

Comment: @DanielMann no warnings/errors. Everything is okay. `Restore completed in 519.83 ms for d:\a\1\s.....\....csproj`

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: @Stanley nope.. It took me too long for the companies project, so I published by command-line and copy/paste to server. I'm going to start a new private project next week with .net 5 so I will give it another try and possibly can update this here :)

Comment: @MatthiasBurger Thanks for the update, my problem was with the ILoggerService, turned out my git repo had .gitignor Log... took me about 6 hours to figure out. This article is great 

https://dev.to/lasanga/setting-up-ci-cd-pipeline-to-deploy-a-net-core-application-to-an-iis-server-through-azure-devops-53o1

Comment: @Stanley thanks for the article. yeah azure pipeline sometimes is complicated. Though it's great when it works...

Answer (score 0):

This issue look like about dependencies fail. It should because your project have referenced the dependencies, but did not installed them during the pipeline.

You can try with executing `dotnet restore` first before calling your `VSBuild` task.

Comment: This returns a `Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.` It stops when it tries this in an angular website project (sure, it cannot do this with angular), can't it just skip that project and continue with the other projects?

Comment: Does this error message occurred in the log of dotnet restore task?